# MS Access 2000 Application - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

I have an old MS Access 2000 application which connects to a SQL Server 2000 database.  I need to migrate this database and application to a new server with SQL Server 2012.  The Access application is running locally on my user's workstation.

Should I upgrade the Access database to a new version then create a new connection to the 2012 SQL Server (new adp file)?  The application is unsupported and we need to move the database to a new server.

Comment: what have you tried?  also, sql server 2017 is out, if you're upgrading why not go to a more recent version?

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you use an .accdb file, not an .adp file. Support for .adp has been removed since Access 2013.

Migrating will vary depending on the application, but quite often isn't an issue at all. Access has high compatibility between versions, and so has MS SQL server.

You can ask about specific problems here or on Stack Overflow depending on the nature of the problem.